# Django-CMS: How to access extended fields of the Title model

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I need to extend the Title model as I want to provide a teaser to every page of a multi lingual project. I was able to create the desired extended fields and a cms-toolbar item to assign values to the extended fields.

How can I access extended fields of the Title model in django-cms-3.0.12 as they are not available via {% page_attribute 'extended_field' %} in the template. The django-cms documentation does not seem to provide an answer to my question, nor am I able to find an easy solution in the cms code base as well.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You would access the data via the request current_page object found in the template context... For example:

```
{{ request.current_page.iconextension.field }}
```

[Doc ref](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html#using-extensions-in-templates)

Comment: This does work on extended fields in the Page model but it does not seem to work on the Title model. For example, i have a class TeaserExtension(TitleExtension) and a field called 'teaser'. If i now call {{ request.current_page.teaserextension.teaser }} i get no value returned.

Comment: Ok! I finaly got it, I misunderstood the table model. I managed to call it by its related name.